# how to crop by rectangular in angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-img-crop

I am using ng2-img-cropper for image crop but if the image is in rectangular shape then it does not capture the whole image, I am not able to crop by rectangular size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code  :-

```
   //canvas
    this.cropperSettings.canvasWidth = 400;
    this.cropperSettings.canvasHeight = 300;

    //crop size
    this.cropperSettings.croppedWidth = 300;
    this.cropperSettings.croppedHeight = 150;

    //aspect ratio
    this.cropperSettings.width = 150;
    this.cropperSettings.height = 150;

    // keep the original image size (minus cropping)
    this.cropperSettings.preserveSize = true;

    this.cropperSettings.keepAspect = false;
```